# How to update json file after data preprocessing with python

Tags: python, json

After preprocessing data for sentimental analysis using python I have received the following data

```
0     [50, patients, identified, yesterday, kuwait.,...
1     [Digital, giants, alibaba, &amp;, tecent, Chin...
2     [COVID19SL, Update:, 52, patients, reported, l...
3     [52, COVID-19, cases, reported, yesterday, (2...
4     [52, COVID-19, cases, reported, yesterday., Of...
                        ...                        
95                          [1,100+, cases., COVID19SL]
96    [Total, Cases, -, 1106, Active, Cases, -, 423,...
97    [12, Covid-19, positive, patients, reported, i...
98    [12, people, tested, positive, COVID-19., Tota...
99    [, Twelve, new, COVID19, cases, reported, , ...
Name: tweets, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

But when saving into json file the original data has been saved, The code I used is as below

```
import json

df.to_json(r'C:\Users\C\Documents\Python Scripts\twdata.json')

with open('C:\/Users\/C\/Documents\/Python Scripts\/twdata.json') as data:
    alldata=data.read()    
    print(alldata)
```

output:
    {"tweets":{"0":"50 patients identified yesterday are from kuwait. The government....

Could you please help me to sort this issue. I am new to python. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I do not see where you modify json, this code only reads it. Plus there is no code here that supposed to write/append to json. Therefore, when it closes itself after `with open` statement, it will be same.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This gave me a good insight to the problem.